# ngrx - effects chaining with error handling : fetch data from second api if first api fetch was successful

Tags: angular, error-handling, ngrx, chaining, ngrx-effects

I saw some of the SO answers, and [this](https://medium.com/@amcdnl/dispatching-multiple-actions-from-ngrx-effects-c1447ceb6b22) medium post as well, but these still don't solve my current problem.

Scenario:

1. Add a product.
2. If successful, get list of all products.

Each of these two cases can have errors:

1. Business Errors, containing business specific error messages
2. Network errors, generic stuff like 40x error codes etc

Currently, i have the effect that will use a service to add a product, and dispatch an action based on the success of failure of the operation. This will update the store with the currentProduct being set to the added product.

```
  @Effect()
  addProduct$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AddProductAction),
    map((action: AddProductAction) => action.payload),
    switchMap((ProductToAdd: Product) =>
      this.productService.addProduct(ProductToAdd).pipe(
        map(response => {
          if (this.responseContainsBusinessError(response)) {
            return new AddProductBusinessError(response);
          } else { // no business error
            return new AddProductSuccess(response);
          }
        }),
        catchError(err => of(new AddProductFail(err))) // network/http error etc
      )
    )
  );
```

Can someone please show how to change this code so that i can add the second effect/api call to fetch the list of products from the server ?

Comment: I'd recommend using `mergeMap` and dispatching an array of actions: `[new AddProductSuccess(response), new LoadProductsRequest()]` This way, your `addProduct$` effect does not get cluttered and you also have a reusable `LoadProducts` effect.

Comment: how to dispatch the array with the error handling part included? The link i posted used an array with switchmap, i understood the array part, but not how to incorporate my error handling with it

Comment: Just use `mergeMap` instead of `map` and then you can return an array.

Answer (score 4):

Just add another @Effect which will trigger on `AddProductSuccess`.

```
@Effect()
  listAllProducts$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AddProductSuccess),
    ....
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but I think the problem with this solution is that this way you cannot react on the result of the first effect. If the first API call to add the new product fails you don't want to request the product list. (If I understood correctly.)

Comment: You won't request the product list if the API fails this way. The effect will trigger from `return new AddProductSuccess(response);` in your first effect, only if the condition is met (product was retrieved successfully). If error happens, nothing further will be done (listAllProducts$ effect will not be triggered)

Comment: @avramz You're right, I read over the effect name. Saving the added product should still be possible. Sounds like a good solution to me.